Realtime Join by Location and Summary
I have a vector file with multiple polygons and  multiple location points, I am adjusting the polygons and want to get a realtime count as a label maybe as to how many points are in the polygon, is this possible?
Basically I want each polygon to have range bound # of points (180-220, points per polygon)

You can label your polygon layer with the expression:
array_length(overlay_intersects(layer:='mypointlayer', expression:=$id))

Change mypointlayer to the name of your point layer. The expression will create an array of all intersecting points ids, then count all ids in the array.



OMG! Thank you so much, life saver.

Nice! What should I do when someone answers my question?
